# Mixed Complementarity (MCP) Pyomo

Tags: pyomo

Is it possible to solve an mcp models with pyomo? I would appreciate it if someone could point out an example and the solver i could use, if it's possible of course.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, in principle it is: http://prod.sandia.gov/techlib/access-control.cgi/2015/155584.pdf

You need to install the PATH AMPL Solver from this webpage

pages.cs.wisc.edu/~ferris/path.html

If you make it work, could you see if the munson1.py solves the problems correctly in the examples correctly (munson1.py is a MCP), as I had problems so far

groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/pyomo-forum/DxdtrepaU6I

Comment: I've had a look at that... when you have a large system of equations, iteratively adding `complements()` for each row takes painstakingly long. Is there a way to do that more efficiently within `pyomo`? Perhaps some further documentation available on the complementarity features?

Comment: See a related issue here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51853047/error-when-solving-mixed-complementarity-model. I personally think it is a bug.